# Read CSV file in PHP and Validate if its first row contains title and date

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have to upload a csv file using php. but before uploading i need to validate it for two things.

1. if its headers are Title and Date (there are only Colomns).
2. first two rows title should not be same.

here is the strucure of expected file.

```
Title   Date
"The Forest: Season 1: Episode 1",  "7/7/2018"
"Forgive Us Our Debts", "7/7/2018"
"Mr. Sunshine: Season 1: Episode 1",    "7/7/2018"
```

code so far

```
$rows   = array_map('str_getcsv', file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
    $header = array_shift($rows);
    $csv    = array();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
```

i have a csv file in associative array but unable to read the first row.

How to read CSV rows with row indexes?

Comment: Maybe because the header insn't in CSV. The second row looks like its "comma"-seperated but the header looks like "tab"-seperated. Can you show how you tried to access the header?

Comment: @codeneuss, its tab seperated only. to make it readable here i added commas.

Comment: how read first row if i am uisng str_getcsv to covert the csv to array

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
if(isset($csv[0])){    
    if($csv[0][0] != 'Title' || $csv[0][1] != 'Date'){      
        return "Heading(Title and/or Date) is missing.";
    }else{        
        foreach ($csv as $key => $value) {
            //Process further
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

str_getcsv has a comma as default delimiter. And you can only convert one line of CSV. If you want to convert a whole file you should use fgetcsv [https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php]

This code example will work:

```
<?php

$csv = "Title\tDate
\"The Forest: Season 1: Episode 1\"\t\"7/7/2018\"
\"Forgive Us Our Debts\",\t\"7/7/2018\"
\"Mr. Sunshine: Season 1: Episode 1\",\t\"7/7/2018\"";

$rows   = array_map(function ($csv){
    return str_getcsv($csv, "\t");
}, explode("\n",$csv));


$header = array_shift($rows);
$result    = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
   $result[] = array_combine($header,$row);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("file.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

$valid = true;
foreach ($file as $i => $row) {

     if ($i > 1) break;

     list($title, $date) = $row;

     if ($i === 0 && ($title !== 'Title' || $date !== 'Date')) {
          $valid = false;  
     } else {
          $second_row = $file[2];

          if ($title === $second_row[0]) {
              $valid = false;
          }
     }
}
```